# Bson Document to Json in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

This is my code:

```
MongoDBSingleton dbSingleton = MongoDBSingleton.getInstance();
MongoDatabase db;

try {
    db = dbSingleton.getTestdb();
    MongoIterable<String> mg = db.listCollectionNames();
    MongoCursor<String> iterator=mg.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection(iterator.next());

        for (Document doc: table.find()) {  
            System.out.println(doc.toJson());
        }
    }

}
```

This the output of `toJson`:

```
"modified" : { "$date" : 1475789185087}
```

This is my output of `toString`:

```
{"modified":"Fri Oct 07 02:56:25 IST 2016"}
```

I want String date format in Json, how to do it?

Comment: What is your mongo version and java driver version?

Comment: My mongo is 3.2 and driver is 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to produce the plain JSON. Please refer this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/c8lmyg9RvSY/_9kAdHOBYS8J).

However, it can produce JSON in two modes.

1) Strict mode - Output that you have already got

2) Shell mode

**Shell Mode:-**

```
JsonWriterSettings writerSettings = new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL, true);           
System.out.println(doc.toJson(writerSettings));
```

**Output:-**

```
"createdOn" : ISODate("2016-07-16T16:26:51.951Z")
```

[MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Comment: but how to convert this "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-07-16T16:26:51.951Z") to Date(),

Answer (score 10):

Sadly, IMO, MongoDB Java support is broken.

That said, there is a `@deprecated` class in the mongo-java-driver that you can use:

```
String json = com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(document);
System.out.println("JSON serialized Document: " + json);
```

I'm using this to produce fasterxml (jackson) compatible JSON from a `Document` object that I can deserialize via `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyObject.class)`.

However, I'm not sure what they expect you to use now that the `JSON` class is deprecated. But for the time being, it is still in the project (as of v3.4.2).

I'm importing the following in my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Sadly, we need the mongo-java-driver solely to serialize
     Document objects in a sane manner -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using the async driver for actually fetching and pushing updates to mongo, and the non-async driver solely for the use of the `JSON.serialize` method.

Comment: I use `String id = ObjectId.get().toHexString();` rather than storing `ObjectId` directly.

Answer (score 2):

In theory we are supposed to use `toJSON()` per...
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1770

However, it seems that, at least up through 3.6, `toJSON()` isn't supported on various types the old `JSON.serialize()` method handled without issue, such as the `AggregateIterable<Document>` objects output by `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 2020 update to answer exactly your question, i.e. getting this exact format:

```
"modified":"2016-07-16T16:26:51.951Z"
```

You have to use writerSettings like notionquest suggested, but with a custom date converter and *DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT*:

```
public class JsonDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Long> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonDateTimeConverter.class);
    static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    @Override
    public void convert(Long value, StrictJsonWriter writer) {
        try {
            Instant instant = new Date(value).toInstant();
            String s = DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(instant);
            writer.writeString(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Fail to convert offset %d to JSON date", value), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
doc.toJson(JsonWriterSettings
            .builder()
            .dateTimeConverter(new JsonDateTimeConverter())
            .build())
```

Answer (score 1):

if the bson.jar version is > `3.0.0` you may try `document.toJson()`

Answer (score 0):

I used following

```
try {

            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbname");

            MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("nameofcollect");

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            ArrayList<JsonObject> array = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();


            String jsonString = null;
            /*WARNING Gson lib serialize string ->means add slash if you convert "json string" into "json string"*/
            for (Document doc : collection.find()) {
                 jsonString = gson.toJson(doc);              
                 array.add(new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class));
            }

            //String finalarry = gson.toJson(array);

            Map<Object, ArrayList<JsonObject>> seedMap = new HashMap<Object, ArrayList<JsonObject>>();
            // String encode = coCoRy.encryptAndEncode(jsonString);
            seedMap.put("seed", array);     
            String seedJsonString = gson.toJson(seedMap);

            mongoClient.close();

            return seedJsonString;


        } catch (MongoException | ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Result will be like following

```
{
    "seed": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "timestamp": 1590914828,
                "counter": 10457170,
                "randomValue1": 5587428,
                "randomValue2": -25784
            },
            "FIR_EVID_NUM": "3436345346",
            "FIR_REG_NUM": "89678967",
            "LOGIN_ID": "pc_admin",
            "MEDIA_PATH": "C:\\Users\\ALPHAMALE\\Documents\\ShareX\\Screenshots\\2020-05\\1590211570.png"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "timestamp": 1590924463,
                "counter": 7254997,
                "randomValue1": 5012578,
                "randomValue2": 24700
            },
            "FIR_EVID_NUM": "999999",
            "FIR_REG_NUM": "888888",
            "LOGIN_ID": "32323",
            "MEDIA_PATH": "C:/uploads/c46847c7e2d130ffd746c789c0f0932e.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final JsonWriterSettings settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder( ).outputMode( JsonMode.SHELL ).build( );

System.out.println(doc.toJson(settings));
```

You can change the JsonMode is you wish